# Fat Tails and Volatility clustering relationship

Tags: arima, autocorrelation, garch, qq-plot, fat-tails

Let's say I have a return time series that after a proper ARMA modelling exhibits fat-tallness from QQ-plot.

Can this be a consequence of *volatility clustering* so that by applying a GARCH model I can obtain normally distributed residuals? When is this the case (if any)?

In other words: what's the relationship between significant autocorrelation in squared residuals and leptokurtosis?

Comment: Short answer: the relationship is there. Volatility clustering produces heavier tails. This should be described in some of the early ARCH-GARCH literature. (Since I do not have a reference, I am only posting this as a comment.)

Comment: @Richard Hardy Thank you for your comment! So if I model a GARCH and the variables results statistically significant but QQ-plot does not "improve" what can I conclude?

Comment: **Engle's** original ARCH paper (p. 992) says *The first-order ARCH process generates data with fatter tails than the normal density.* **Bollerslev's** original GARCH paper (p. 313) says *Hence the GARCH(1,1) process is leptokurtic (heavily tailed), a property the process shares with the ARCH(q) process; cf. Milhoj (1984).* And **Tsay** "Analysis of Financial Time Series" (2010, 3rd edition, p. 133) says *Consequently, similar to ARCH models, the tail distribution of a GARCH(1,1) process is heavier than that of a normal distribution.*

Comment: You should be looking at the QQ plot of standardized residuals from the GARCH model, not raw residuals. They should match the assumed distribution (you can assume nonnormal distributions for standardized residuals).

Comment: @Richard Hardy Great you're right! Just to be sure, so the same (standardise the residuals before) would apply if I want to investigate whether a t-distribution fit better in my Garch model, right? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Yes. If you assume a $t$ distribution when fitting your GARCH model, use the same $t$ distribution when doing the QQ plot on standardized residuals.

Comment: @Richard Hardy yes but after computing a GARCH with normal innovation can I look at both std residual QQ plots against normal and different distributions (e.g. student-t)? My reasoning would be that if I see a better fit from a t-distribution QQ-plot, this motivate a GARCH with t innovations inspection. Is this a wrong reasoning process?

Comment: You could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship is there; volatility clustering produces heavier tails. Engle's original ARCH paper (p. 992) says

> The first-order ARCH process generates data with fatter tails than the normal density.

Bollerslev's original GARCH paper (p. 313) says

> Hence the GARCH(1,1) process is leptokurtic (heavily tailed), a property the process shares with the ARCH(q) process; cf. Milhoj (1984).

And Tsay's "Analysis of Financial Time Series" (2010, 3rd edition, p. 133) says

> Consequently, similar to ARCH models, the tail distribution of a GARCH(1,1) process is heavier than that of a normal distribution.

after giving a proof of one special case.

**References**

- Engle, R. F. (1982). [Autoregressive conditional heteroscedasticity with estimates of the variance of United Kingdom inflation.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1912773) *Econometrica: Journal of the Econometric Society, 50*(4), 987-1007.
- Bollerslev, T. (1986). [Generalized autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304407686900631) *Journal of econometrics, 31*(3), 307-327.
- Tsay, R. S. (2005). [*Analysis of financial time series*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470644560) (Vol. 543). John Wiley & Sons.